# Dereferencing a pointer to an object to call constructor

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle 
{
public:
    enum TwoAxleDrives { FRONT, REAR, ALL, NONE };
    enum TwoAxleVehicles { BIKE, CAR, TRAILER };
private:
    TwoAxleVehicles type;
    TwoAxleDrives drive;

    float km;
public:
    Vehicle() {}

    Vehicle(float km)
    {
        this->km = km;
    }

    static Vehicle *factory(Vehicle::TwoAxleVehicles type)
    {
        Vehicle *vehicle = new Vehicle;
        vehicle->type = type;

        return vehicle;
    }

    static Vehicle *factory(Vehicle::TwoAxleVehicles type, Vehicle::TwoAxleDrives drive)
    {
        Vehicle *vehicle = new Vehicle;
        vehicle->type = type;
        vehicle->drive = drive;

        return vehicle;
    }

    float getKM()
    {
        return this->km;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vehicle *bike = Vehicle::factory(Vehicle::BIKE);
    Vehicle *bmw = Vehicle::factory(Vehicle::CAR, Vehicle::REAR);

    (*bmw)(100.8f);

    cout << "BMW, " << bmw->getKM() << "km" << endl; // BMW, 100.8km

    delete bike, bmw;
}
```

Our teacher in school sent the code for this class. When I tried dereferening `*bmw` and calling the second constructor, I got the following error : `error: no match for call to ‘(Vehicle) (float)’`. The problem comes from this statement from the `main()` function: `(*bmw)(100.8f);`. This is not a function pointer, but a pointer to an object. I do not understand what is wrong.

Comment: Constructors are not something you can call on an existing object, either through a pointer or otherwise. The only place you can call a constructor is when creating a new object.

Comment: For this you might want to do some research about *template parameter packs* and *perfect forwarding*. Then your factory functions could take optional extra arguments that it forwards to the constructor when creating the object.

Comment: Unrelated: Prefer using the member initializer list in your constructor: `Vehicle(float km) : km(km) {}`